# Printing a web page to POS Printer

Tags: c#, printing, printing-web-page

Does anyone know if it is possible to print from HTML to  a Espon Pos Printer? 
Can it be done in active x?

I created the application to work with regular printers and not the department wants a pos printer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the Epson POS printers and they only accept strings, meaning you are not able to just slap HTML tags and expect it to print it out.  This means that for new lines, you need to put \n instead of < br/>

I assume that you are using the .NET wrapper for the Epson printer.
To print the HTML tagged strings, you might have to just parse that HTML and remove the tags then see if you can print the strings.

Comment: Ok. I think i would have to build an app to just print the receipts. But i have another problem I am using the .net wrapper but it cannot find no pos printer ( PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer();)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install OPOS drivers for that printer, usually you can find them on the manufacturers web-site. After you install it you choose a printer from the list and after that it will become visible with PosExplorer. At least it worked with me, I worked with Star Micronics POS printers but there should be no difference in the approach.